# Stack navigator doesn't work in release apk

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have Drawer and Stack navigators in my app
drawer

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Games" component={GamesScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

stack

```
import Cities from "../components/games/Cities";
const GScreen =({navigation}) =>{
  return(
    /*code*/
  )
}
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export default class GamesScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Games' component={GScreen}  options={{headerTitle:(props) => <Header props= 
          {this.state} {...props} />}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='Cities' component={Cities} options={{headerTitle:(props) => <Header props= 
           {this.state} {...props} />}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

My app is working fine in debug mode, but in release only the drawer works.

When i ckick on a component just nothing happens

Comment: have you imported `react-native-gesture-handler` in your entry file?

Comment: no, I haven't heard of such a package, but I will try it

Comment: @FahadFarooq I tried your advice, but unfortunately it didn't help